# How to plot "count" and "identity" in the same graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a list of decimal numbers, ranging from 1 to 40K and I am trying to plot a frequency histogram together with the total sum of a given `bin`. I'm attempting to do it using `ggplot2` but getting lost on how to use the same x axis bins from the histogram:

```
sales <- data.frame(amount = runif(100, min=0, max=40000))
h <- hist(sales$amount, breaks=b)
sales$groups <- cut(sales$amount, breaks=h$breaks)
ggplot(sales,aes(x=groups)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="count")+
  geom_bar(aes(x=groups, y=amount), stat="identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*5, name = "sum"))
```

I managed to create both graphs independently, but they seem to overwrite each other.

[image: using <code>stat="identity"</code>]

or

[image: using <code>stat="count"</code>]

Comment: can you define what is `vendas`, `b`, and `groups` ?

Comment: @dc37 sorry, missed variable names from my scratch code. Fixed, the data represents some sales history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, you tried to plot two different variables (Count and Sum) in the bar graph. As they have really different ranges, you need to define a secondary y axis.

First, the grammar of `ggplot2` asks for one for column for x values, one column for y values and one or several columns for groups (I'm doing a very brief and dirty summary of my understanding of how `ggplot2` works).

Here, the idea is to have your "breaks" as x variable, a second column with all y values to be plot and a group column stipulating if a y value belongs to the group "Count" or "amount". You can achieve this using `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages:

```r
set.seed(123)
sales <- data.frame(amount = runif(100, min=0, max=40000))
b = 4
h <- hist(sales$amount, breaks=b)
sales$groups <- cut(sales$amount, breaks=h$breaks)

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
sales %>% group_by(groups) %>% mutate(Count = n()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(.,cols = c(Count, amount), names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Value")

# A tibble: 200 x 3
# Groups:   groups [4]
   groups        Variable  Value
   <fct>         <chr>     <dbl>
 1 (1e+04,2e+04] Count       27 
 2 (1e+04,2e+04] amount   11503.
 3 (3e+04,4e+04] Count       27 
 4 (3e+04,4e+04] amount   31532.
 5 (1e+04,2e+04] Count       27 
 6 (1e+04,2e+04] amount   16359.
 7 (3e+04,4e+04] Count       27 
 8 (3e+04,4e+04] amount   35321.
 9 (3e+04,4e+04] Count       27 
10 (3e+04,4e+04] amount   37619.
# … with 190 more rows
```

However, if you are trying to plot this straight you will get a bad plot with bars for "Count" really small compared to "amount":

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
sales %>% group_by(groups) %>% mutate(Count = n()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(.,cols = c(Count, amount), names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Value")%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=groups, y = Value, fill = Variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_dodge())
```

[image]

So, you can try to pass a secondary y axis using `sec.axis` argument in `scale_y_continuous`. However, this won't change your plot, it will simply create a "fake" right axis with the scale modify by the value you pass on the argument `sec.axis`:
[image]

So, if you want to have both group of values visible on your graph you need to either scale down "amount" or scale up "Count" in order that both group have a similar range of values.

Here, as you want to have the sum on the right axis, we will scale down the "Sum" in order it get values in the same range than "Count" values.

On the graph, you can see that "amount" values is reaching around 40000 whereas the maximal value of "Count" is 30. So, you can choose the following scale factor: 40000 / 30 = 1333.333.

So, now, if you create a second column called "Amount" that is the result of "amount" divided by 1300, you will have "Amount" and "Count" on the same range. So, your data will looks like that now:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

sales %>% group_by(groups) %>% mutate(Count = n()) %>% 
  mutate(Amount = amount /1300) %>%
  pivot_longer(.,cols = c(Count, Amount), names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Value")

# A tibble: 200 x 4
# Groups:   groups [4]
   amount groups        Variable Value
    <dbl> <fct>         <chr>    <dbl>
 1 24000. (2e+04,3e+04] Count     30  
 2 24000. (2e+04,3e+04] Amount    18.5
 3 13313. (1e+04,2e+04] Count     30  
 4 13313. (1e+04,2e+04] Amount    10.2
 5 19545. (1e+04,2e+04] Count     30  
 6 19545. (1e+04,2e+04] Amount    15.0
 7 38179. (3e+04,4e+04] Count     20  
 8 38179. (3e+04,4e+04] Amount    29.4
 9 19316. (1e+04,2e+04] Count     30  
10 19316. (1e+04,2e+04] Amount    14.9
# … with 190 more rows
```

In order the secondary y axis reflect the reality of "amount" values, you can pass the opposite scale factor and multiply it by 1300.

Altogether, you get the following code:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
sales %>% group_by(groups) %>% mutate(Count = n()) %>% 
  mutate(Amount = amount /1300) %>%
  pivot_longer(.,cols = c(Count, Amount), names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=groups, y = Value, fill = Variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_dodge()) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Count",sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*1300, name = "Sum"))
```

[image]

Thus, you have the illusion to have plot two different group of values on two different scales.

Hope that this long explanation was helpful for you.

Comment: this is awesome. thank you, wil take the time to digest it.

Comment: Glad that it looks what you are looking for. If you have any questions, feel free to ask it ;)

Comment: haha ;) I should have explain that more in details. 1300 is an arbitrary ratio that I choose to have max of count and max of sum be close together (you can see 40 000 / 300. Actually, we are not telling to ggplot to draw y1 and y2. we are telling to draw one y for two groups and I use a scaled value of "amount" to be in the same range than "count". I will edit my post later today to explain more deeply what I have done

Comment: I edited my answer in order to describe a little bit more the use of a scale factor and sec.axis. Hope it helps. Let me knwo fi it is ok or if there is some shadows parts ;)